# Strange file directories that I cannot delete

Tags: mount, rsync, nfs

I used rsync to copy a TON of data to a new nfs server.  Now I have a pile of really strange stuff.

```
nfsparent@clientsandbox:/home$ ls -la
total 124
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root       test 4096 Jun 30 08:32 ..
drwxr-x---  2 user1 test 64 Jun 30 08:31 user1
drwxr-x---  2 user2 test 64 Jun 20 10:37 user2
drwxr-x---  2 user3 test 64 Jun 16 06:51 user3
drwxr-x---  2 user4 test 64 Jun 16 06:50 user4
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.13-13:00:03
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.13-18:00:04
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.14-13:00:24
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.14-18:00:09
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.15-13:00:04
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.15-18:00:04
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.16-13:00:05
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.16-18:00:13
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.19-13:00:07
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.19-18:00:16
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.20-13:00:02
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.20-18:00:03
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.21-13:00:06
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.21-18:01:43
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.22-13:00:04
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.22-18:00:37
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.23-13:00:07
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.23-18:00:03
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.26-13:00:04
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.26-18:00:05
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.27-13:00:04
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.27-18:00:08
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.28-13:00:04
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.28-18:00:03
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.29-13:00:05
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.29-18:00:03
drwxrwxrw-  2 nfsparent  test 4096 Jun 30 08:38 .@GMT-2017.06.30-13:00:03
drwxr-xr-x  2 user5 test 4096 Jun 15 20:50 user5
drwxr-x---  2 user6 test 64 Jun 16 06:51 user6
drwx------  2 user6 test  64 Jun 29 14:40 user7
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root           64 Jun 30 08:38 test
```

What the heck are those .@GMT* directories and how do I get rid of them.  I can move them, but I cannot do anything else.  Deleting them shows Read only file system.  These files are mounted from a host server, and rw is being used as an option, so remounting isn't helping.

Is this some weird rsync thing?

Comment: It's interesting that all directories are name at 13:00 and 18:00. Is there a cron job that's kicking off somewhere from user nfsparent?

Comment: I believe that the "@GMT" refers to "Greenwich Mean Time"

Comment: @CharlesGreen yes, but I'm referring to the fact that all of the dirs were created on Jun 30, but have date/time encoded filenames. Related to rsync?

Comment: @heynnema Just clarifying the op's statement in second to last paragraph "What the heck are those .@GMT* directories..."

Comment: Someone at work pointed me to look at shadow copies since the NFS server is Windows.  It lines up perfectly.

Strange thing though, my other windows nfs server implementation also has shadow copies turned on but does not have the same behavior when viewing from linux.

Answer (score 0):

They are very much indeed most definitely shadow copies, and also discussed over at https://serverfault.com/questions/357069/how-to-hide-shadow-copies-in-nfs-shares which might at least point you in the right direction.